# Xml data in an ASP.Net Dynamic Data Site

Tags: asp.net, xml, dynamic-data

I have this problem where I can't get my dynamic data web app to save xml data into a text field. Maybe this is a common problem but searching the web doesn't give me any answers...

So heres the steps to recreate my problem:

- I have database with a table that has a column of type "ntext" (Sql Server 2005).
- I create a new Dynamic Data Entities Web Application, within this I create an ADO Entity Data Model and add the table with the ntext column.
- I setup the global.ascx file and fire up the web app.
- When the web app opens I navigate to the table and insert a new item
- In the text box thats generated and represents the ntext column, i insert some xml (simple cut and paste from Notepad) and hit the Insert/Save button.
- The insert fails with a the error:

  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Example of xml attempted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<item></item>
</root>
```

Typing a string of characters eg "hello world" works!

Can anyone help and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably becuase it sees what you are adding in a potential dangerous request.  I would assume you have ValidateRequest="true" in the page directive.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Just as a sidenote.

Setting validateRequest="false" for all the pages should be avoided when possible, IMO. Whenever you've a scenario where you've to disable it, set it on the page level ( <%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" ..%>.

Also, on the pages where you do this, **make sure you're validating the input**, so nothing harmful gets passed on.

Answer (score 0):

Can i just say REA_ANDREW you're a genius! I updated this at the web.config and it now works:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

Comment: Thanks, I would love that to be true.  May be in another 40 years I may get close.  I agree with snomag, and I apologise for not making clear that my intention was to convey its usage a page level not globally.  Apologies for that.